# HQL - order by dynamic (aliased) property

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I have the following `Entity` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User {

  @Id
  @Column
  private UUID id

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;
}
```

what I need is to perform ordering by generated (dynamic) field, made of concatenation of first name and last name.

Having HQL query like

```
select u,concat(u.firstName, u.lastName) as fullName From User u order by fullName DESC
```

throws `No property fullName found for type User!`

Is there any way I can do it **without having to change table schema** (I mean, adding field `full_name` on database level)?

Native SQL (Postgres) **allows** ordering by generated, aliased fields.

Comment: `ORDER BY firstName DESC, lastName DESC` will behave in absolutely the same way as if concated.

Comment: I know that, but angular frontend concates it itself to field `fullName` and sends only one parameter `sortColumn=fullName`. Can't do much about it.

Comment: Is the sort parameter from `Pageable` interface or passed as ordinal request parameter?